# Are all T Tauris on the Hayashi track?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, t-tauri-stars

Reading the definitions of [T Tauri stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_Tauri_star) and the [Hayashi track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayashi_track) one can gather that:

> T Tauri stars are pre-main-sequence stars in the process of contracting to the main sequence along the Hayashi track

and that:

> After a protostar ends its phase of rapid contraction and becomes a T Tauri star, it is extremely luminous. The star continues to contract, but much more slowly. While slowly contracting, the star follows the Hayashi track

Can we then say that **all** stars on the Hayashi track are T Tauri stars? And moreover, are **all** T Tauris on the Hayashi track?

Comment: To clarify, is your question "Are all T-tauri stars on the Hayashi Track?"  or   "Are all stars on the Hayashi Track T-tauri stars"  (or are you asking both questions?)

Comment: Now that you mention it, probably both!

Comment: somewhat T-Tauri related [History, significance and "drama" (if any) of T-Tauri stars, especially the early bits?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/49179/7982) and [Why would radio astronomers choose ¹³CO and C¹⁸O spectral lines instead of the most isotopically common combination?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47375/7982)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very much a case of semantics and what exactly you mean by a T Tauri star.

If a requirement is for the star to have a significant disc, then no, a fair fraction of young stars, particularly those of low mass, have lost their discs before they reach the end of the Hayashi track. The exponential decay timescale for losing a disc is around 3 Myr. The timescale to get to the bottom of the Hayashi track can be 10-100 Myr for stars of 0.5-0.1 solar masses.

If the definition encompasses both "classical" T Tauri stars and "weak-lined" T Tauri stars (those without an active accretion disc), then yes, all young stars on the Hayashi track are T-Tauri stars.

Edit: I realised I hadn't completed the answer. It is also true that many higher mass T-Tauri stars (more than 0.5 solar masses) have left the Hayashi track and still have discs whilst they are on their radiative Henyey tracks.